# Not all code paths return a value why is the happpening for my HAM Shortwave radio app

Tags: c#, chat, irc

So I am coding a Windows Console app in C# that is for Shortwave HAM Radio DX enthusiasts to look Number Station and oddity broadcast times on their desktop. I am using Visual Studio Community edition as my compiler.

What is happening is the compiler is returning these errors:

How this app works is by connecting to priyom.orgs IRC channel and then users can use the !n command to look up which station is broadcasting next. But I cannot find what value is not returned:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoKMk.png)

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gguPR.png
Here is the code:

   
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace irc_bot
{
    class Program
    {

        private const string server = "chat.freenode.net";
        private const string gecos = "Cerk";
        private const string nick = "Priyomwindowsapp";
        private const string ident = "Priyomwindowsapp";
        private const string channel = "#priyom";

        static string Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new TcpClient())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Numbers Station Finder. From here you can search for Number Station broadcast times and other shortwave / HAM radio oddities right from your Windows desktop. I will also present a link to navigate to in your web browser to listen in real time. For note, I use priyom.orgs IRC server. While on the IRC server you will have the nickname Priyomwindowsapp. To display the next signal to broadcast type !n. To search for a signal type !n space enigma ID (!n HM01 for example). Program C 2020 keifmeister.");

                Console.WriteLine($"Connecting to {server}");
                client.Connect(server, 6667);
                Console.WriteLine($"Connected: {client.Connected}");

                using (var stream = client.GetStream())
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine($"USER {ident} * 8 {gecos}");
                    writer.WriteLine($"NICK {nick}");
                    // identify with the server so your bot can be an op on the channel
                    writer.WriteLine($"PRIVMSG NickServ :IDENTIFY {nick}");
                    writer.Flush();

                    while (client.Connected)
                    {
                        var data = reader.ReadLine();

                        if (data != null)
                        {
                            var d = data.Split(' ');
                            Console.WriteLine($"Data: {data}");

                            if (d[0] == "PING")
                            {
                                writer.WriteLine("PONG");
                                writer.Flush();
                            }

                            if (d.Length > 1)
                            {

                                switch (d[1])
                                {
                                    case "376":
                                    case "422":
                                        {
                                            writer.WriteLine($"JOIN {channel}");

                                            // communicate with everyone on the channel as soon as the bot logs in
                                            Console.WriteLine("Enter username to be logged into:");
                                            string message = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                                            writer.WriteLine(message);

                                            writer.Flush();
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    case "PRIVMSG":
                                        {
                                            if (d.Length > 2)
                                            {
                                                if (d[2] == nick)
                                                {
                                                    // someone sent a private message to the bot
                                                    var sender = data.Split('!')[0].Substring(1);
                                                    var message = data.Split(':')[2];
                                                    Console.WriteLine($"Message: {message}");
                                                    // handle all your bot logic here
                                                    writer.WriteLine($@"PRIVMSG {sender} : {message}");
                                                    writer.Flush();
                                                }

                                            }
                                            break;

                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoKMk.png)

Answer (score 3):

You are returning a `string` from your `Main`, so the static analysis thinks you want to *return* a result. It's likely you actually want:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Main() and command-line arguments (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/):

> Main can either have a void, int, or, starting with C# 7.1, Task, or
> Task return type.

Worthy comment from [Hayden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4406995/hayden):

> Also make sure that your Project Output type is Console Application
> (right click your Project > Properties > Application tab in Visual
> Studio).

Comment: Also make sure that your Project Output type is `Console Application` (right click your Project > Properties > Application tab in Visual Studio).

Comment: That indeed fixed that error, but it is still returning:

Comment: @KeiferBly what you have yourself there, is a bonafide "*another question*"

Comment: @KeiferBly returning as the console is closing? Try adding a `Console.ReadLine` line at the end of your code.

Comment: No I solved that issue, but now it is picking up for the message that there is no text to send. odd.....